# Filtering out integer from NSManaged object

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have the following core data property

```
@NSManaged public var part: [Int]?
```

and it may contain 0 or 1 or both. I am trying to filter out the `part` which contains 1 and did this

```
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"part == %@", 1)
```

But I am getting the error

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)

if I do the above. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any ? Since it’s an array, you want that if one of the part value is 1 ?

Comment: What is the error that you're facing?

Comment: Tried ANY, didn't work

Comment: Do you want the count of 1's from the array?

Comment: @BhargavR, that's what I want

Comment: @Daniel, tried this fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"part == 1")  as well as %i, didn't work.

Comment: @TheTiger, none of the above worked.

Comment: Relevant: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html and https://academy.realm.io/posts/nspredicate-cheatsheet/

Comment: Can an `NSManaged` property be declared as **array** at all? I strongly doubt that.

Comment: I'm Agree with @vadian, How can `NSManaged` be  an array?

Comment: @vadian, so how do I solve this

Comment: There are a few ways. For example map the `Int` array to a comma (or whatever) separated string and vice versa with a computed property.

Comment: @vadian, thanks for pointing out the obvious mistake about NSManaged property. I have to change that, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've written, i.e.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"part == %@", 1)
```

In the above code, you're trying to `filter` all the `fetched rows` based on whether `part is 1 or not`. So basically here you're using `part` as an `Int`. But as per the declaration, `part` is an `array [Int]`.

It will definitely `throw` an `exception`.

You need to `filter each row after fetching` like:

```
let filteredPart = part.filter({ $0 == 1 })
```

Comment: Appreciate your explanation, so I cannot apply it as a predicate to the fetch request.

Comment: Right. You can't. `part` is a `property` of a single `row`. `fetchRequest.predicate` apply `filter` to all the fetched `rows`.

Comment: @Coder221, do you want to fetch all the objects which have `1` in their `part` property or do you want to do something with `part` property itself?

Comment: @user28434 I just want to fetch all the objects which have 1 in the part, nothing more

Comment: @Coder221, Then this answer won't help. You should use predicate with `IN`, like `%@ IN SELF.part` Or `CONTAINS`

Comment: @user28434,you are correct. Do you mind, explaining a bit more with proper syntax or answering it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use below code :

```
let filteredArray = part.filter() { $0 == 1 }
print(filteredArray.count)
```

You'll get the desired result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using Predicate too:
Use the following code:

```
let part = [1,3,4,7,2,1,4,3,1,5,6,7,1,3,4,8,9,1]
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF == %d",1)
let result = (part as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate)
print(result)
```

> Output:
>
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Comment: Instead, you can use filter function directly like `part.filter({ $0 == 1 })`

Comment: Yes, but Coder221 wants to achieve it using Predicate, so it is an alternate approach by which we can get the same result.

Comment: Coder221 want to set predicate on `NSFetchRequest` not on array.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use filter for that (Swift 4.2)**

```
let arrInt = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]

 let ones = arrInt.filter({$0 == 1})

 print(ones)
```

**Output:**

```
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```